# FileUpload changing inputstream content

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload, save, filesystems

I have two fileupload controls that allow user to upload 2 pictures at the same time. Once the user selects the picture, I use 2 method to resize and crop the posted image and then save it to the file system. The problem occurs when I want to save that resized and  cropped image to the file system. I've used the following code:

```
     protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile!=null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength>0)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(DateTime.Now.Ticks + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(DateTime.Now.Ticks + FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
                    CropImage(FileUpload1);
                    CropImage(FileUpload2);
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + fileName);
                    FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + fileName2);
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                }
            }

            private void CropImage(FileUpload fileup)
            {
                System.Drawing.Image image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileup.PostedFile.InputStream);
                int x = image2.Width;
                int y = image2.Height;
                System.Drawing.Image resizedImage = UIHelper.ResizeImage(image2, new System.Drawing.Size(1140,x/y*1140));
                System.Drawing.Image croppedImage = UIHelper.CropImage(resizedImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 1140, 650));

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                croppedImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
// getting bytes from the cropped image;
                byte[] slika = ms.ToArray();

 fileup.PostedFile.InputStream.Write(slika, 0, slika.Length);
 // changing the original input stream with the cropped one               
            }
```

Now I would like to replace the bytes of the original fileupload input stream with cropped one. Can someone tell me if I'm doing this the wrong way or I'm just not seeing whats wrong here??

The error that I'm getting is this:

" The specified method is not supported", 
in this line of code:

```
 fileup.PostedFile.InputStream.Write(slika, 0, slika.Length);
```

Any solutions? Thanks!!

Comment: what problem do u have?

Comment: It says " The specified method is not supported", in this line of code:  fileup.PostedFile.InputStream.Write(slika, 0, slika.Length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the resized image to disk, you have to use another method:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("yourPath..slika.jpg", slika);
```

and use

> "using"

to dispose it safely

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

        }
```